# замена LinearLayout на другой LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

есть два LinearLayout buttonLinearLayout и nextButtonLinearLayout. На данный момент они находятся один под другим. В коде в зависимости от надобности один скрывается другой появляется таким вот кодом.

```
nextButtonLinearLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
buttonLinearLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
```

Но есть проблема в том, что кнопки находятся  на разных местах по высоте и получается некрасивый переход. Просьба подсказать, как сделать так чтобы кнопки были на одном уровне.

Код активности ниже.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/jokeTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/joke_text_view" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yesButton"
        style="?attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/yesButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/noButton"
        style="?attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/noButton" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/nextButtonLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        style="?attr/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/nextButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так, `INVISIBLE` делает просто невыдимым, а `GONE` буд-то "убирает"

```
 nextButtonLinearLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
 buttonLinearLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!